# Heaviside function as solution of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Reading a book, I saw that this function (where $H$ is the standard Heaviside function)

$$
u(t,x)= H(x-0.5t)
$$

could be the solution, in the sense of distributions, of this equation

$$
u_t + (u^{2})_{x} = 0
$$

i.e

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\int^\ u f_{t} + u^{2}f_{x} dx \right) dt = -\int^\ u_0(x)f(0,x) dx
$$
for any test function $f = f(t,x)$.

Can anyone help me do this verification by computing the above integral?

Regards

Comment: It seems that you are considering the inviscid Burgers' equation $u_t + (\frac{1}{2}u^2)_x = 0$ instead (otherwise Rankine-Hugoniot would not be satisfied). You may have a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2003742).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically when you integrate something times a heaviside function, you just get the integral of that function with domain such that the argument of said heaviside function is greater than $0$. Also note, heaviside function squared is just heaviside function.

$\int_0^\infty (\int u f_t + u^2 f_x dx) dt = \int_0^\infty (\int_{0.5t}^\infty (f_t + f_x) dx dt$

Split up integral and look at $f_x$ first. When we integrate $f_x$ wrt $x$ we get $f$.

So this term is simply $\int_0^\infty (f(t,\infty)-f(t,0.5t))dt $. My thinking is that $f(t,\infty)$ will be zero as it is a test function thus must be integrable.

$\int_0^\infty \int_0^{2x}f_t dt dx = \int_0^\infty (f(2x,x)-f(0,x)) dx$. Here we rearrange the domain in order change the order of integration.

We will happily cancel the $f(t,0.5t)$ and $f(2x,x)$ terms in our integrals.

Our final answer is $-\int_0^\infty f(0,x)dx$

$u_0(x) = H(x)$, so this matches the answer you have supplied.

Comment: There must be some reason why $0.5$ is used in the answer, and it will be linked to the $u^2$ term.