# Asymptotic solution of conservation law $u_t + (\frac{1}{p}|u|^p)_x = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, perturbation-theory, hyperbolic-equations

For $1 < p < 2$, let $u_p$ be a unique solution to

$u_t + \left(\frac{1}{p}|u|^p\right)_x = 0$,

for initial condition

$u_0(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad x > 0, \\ 0 \quad x < 0.  \end{cases}$

I now want to determine the solution $u(t, x) = \lim \limits_{p \to 1} u_p(t, x)$ of the limit problem

$u_t + (|u|)_x = 0$

with same same initial condition. My problem is that I don't really know how to get started with this or which ansatz to use. I tried using  the Lax-Oleinik formula given by the Evans, but got no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the initial data is non-negative, let's assume that $u$ is non-negative. Therefore, we are left with
$$
u_t + u_x = 0 ,\qquad u(x,0) = u_0(x)
$$
where $u_0$ is the step function.
The solution $u = u_0(x-t)$ is indeed non-negative, therefore this solution is the one obtained for $p=1$. Note that this solution is a contact discontinuity
$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
1 \qquad x> st,\\
0 \qquad x< st.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
with speed $s=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Do you perhaps also have an idea how to get that solution as a limit of the solutions u_p?

Comment: @Hamilton The solution is likely to be a discontinuity for other values of $p$ too. According to [Rankine-Hugoniot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine%E2%80%93Hugoniot_conditions), the shock speed is likely to be dependent on $p$ (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2539265/418542) where the theory is presented). You may need to use the [weak form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2003742/418542) of the PDE